# Generate a merkle tree consistency proof

Tags: cryptography

I read the documentation about merkle tree here: [Certificate Transparency Version 2.0](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-trans-rfc6962-bis-27.html#mht_definition), but I still do not quite understand the algorithm that generate the consistency proof.

The example in the documentation:
[old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1RtH.png)
[new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1coU.png)

The consistency proof between old version and new version is PROOF(3, D[7]) = [c, d, g, l]. c, g are used to verify hash0, and d, l are additionally used to show hash is consistent with hash0.

Can someone show me how to use the algorithm to generate these proof?